# ¿Por qué no lee mis int de otra clase C# Set y Get?

Tags: c#

Cuando ejecuto el código, no para para leer las referencias que hice de otra clase y se pasa hasta el final.

```
namespace Promedio_de_cuatro_numeros
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Numeros n = new Numeros();

            Console.WriteLine(" Ingresa un numero");
            n.Num1 = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(" Ingresa un numero");
            n.Num2 = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(" Ingresa un numero");
            n.Num3 = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(" Ingresa un numero");
            n.Num4 = Console.Read();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(" El promedio de los numeros ingresados es " + n.Promedio);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Proba usando ReadLine en lugar de read

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `Console.Read` devuelve un `int`, pero este `int` será el código del caracter en [*UNICODE*](https://home.unicode.org/).
Va a asignar los valores de los *bytes* de los caracteres que escribas. Si escribes menos de los que pides (en tu caso, 4), va a devolver el 13 (CR) para el primer faltante y 10 (LF) para los siguientes.

Lo que necesitas tú es leer el *input* de la consola con `ReadLine`, que devuelve un *string* y después convertirlo a *int*.

```
static int ReadInt()
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    return int.Parse(input);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Numeros n = new Numeros();
    n.Num1 = ReadInt();
    n.Num2 = ReadInt();
    n.Num3 = ReadInt();
    // ...
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: habria que usar try parse, y probar que lo que se ingreso por consola sea valido...

Comment: Sí, totalmente. He preferido no entrar en demasiados detalles...